# Surface normal calculation from depth map in python

Tags: python, opencv, normals

I try to implement following c++ code in python:

```
depth.convertTo(depth, CV_64FC1); // I do not know why it is needed to be 
transformed to 64bit image my input is 32bit

Mat nor(depth.size(), CV_64FC3);

for(int x = 1; x < depth.cols - 1; ++x)
{
   for(int y = 1; y < depth.rows - 1; ++y)
   {
      Vec3d t(x,y-1,depth.at<double>(y-1, x)/*depth(y-1,x)*/);
      Vec3d l(x-1,y,depth.at<double>(y, x-1)/*depth(y,x-1)*/);
      Vec3d c(x,y,depth.at<double>(y, x)/*depth(y,x)*/);
      Vec3d d = (l-c).cross(t-c);
      Vec3d n = normalize(d);
      nor.at<Vec3d>(y,x) = n;
   }
}

imshow("normals", nor);
```

python code:

```
d_im = cv2.imread("depth.jpg")
d_im = d_im.astype("float64")

normals = np.array(d_im, dtype="float32")
h,w,d = d_im.shape
for i in range(1,w-1):
  for j in range(1,h-1):
    t = np.array([i,j-1,d_im[j-1,i,0]],dtype="float64")
    f = np.array([i-1,j,d_im[j,i-1,0]],dtype="float64")
    c = np.array([i,j,d_im[j,i,0]] , dtype = "float64")
    d = np.cross(f-c,t-c)
    n = d / np.sqrt((np.sum(d**2)))
    normals[j,i,:] = n

cv2.imwrite("normal.jpg",normals*255)
```

input image:

[image]

c++ code output:

[image]

my python code output:

[image]

i can not find reason of these differences. How i can get c++ code output with python?

Comment: Actually when I test it, my Python output looks reasonable; what versions of the used modules do you have installed? (`pip list --local`)

Comment: opencv-python 3.4.3.18, numpy 1.15.2

Comment: okay, my versions are: cv2: 3.4.3, numpy: 1.13.1. So I don't think, that this is the problem. I have to admit, that [my image](https://imgur.com/a/AiGB7nE) still doesn't look as smooth as your C++ image. I have one question: In Python you construct your vectors with `d_im[j-1,i,0]`; in C++ you write `depth.at<double>(y-1, x)` why don't you need three indices in C++?`

Comment: Actually, i take c++ codes from [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/82453/calculate-surface-normals-from-depth-image-using-neighboring-pixels-cross-product/), and i gues input image is grayscale so there is no need to third index. When i read input image in python, it returns 3 dimensions,( H,W,C), so i need third index in python.

Comment: Okay after tinkering around with the code and eventually supersampling the image, I had the idea to look what depth the original image has. The image I downloaded from you is an 8-bit image! So what you are seeing there with your Python script is a combination of very low bit depth and horrible jpeg artefacts. You should try an get a better testing image

Comment: This also explains why I did get a better result: images on SO are png; so there were no jpeg artefacts for me

Comment: okey, i can get result like yours'.Now, do you have any idea about differences between c++ 's output and python output's.?

Comment: Assuming that the visualization is done by taking the 3 components of the normal for R,G and B I don't understand why the background is black. There is no depth difference in the background, so the third component of the normal should be +/-1.

Answer (score 6):

As *user8408080* said you output seems to have artifacts caused by the jpeg format. Also keep in mind that importing an 8-bit image as a depth map will not give the same results than using directly the depth map matrix.

Regarding your python code, my advice would be to use vectorized functions and avoid loops as much as you can (it's very slow).

```
zy, zx = np.gradient(d_im)  
# You may also consider using Sobel to get a joint Gaussian smoothing and differentation
# to reduce noise
#zx = cv2.Sobel(d_im, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)     
#zy = cv2.Sobel(d_im, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)

normal = np.dstack((-zx, -zy, np.ones_like(d_im)))
n = np.linalg.norm(normal, axis=2)
normal[:, :, 0] /= n
normal[:, :, 1] /= n
normal[:, :, 2] /= n

# offset and rescale values to be in 0-255
normal += 1
normal /= 2
normal *= 255

cv2.imwrite("normal.png", normal[:, :, ::-1])
```

Comment: Very good answer, as it also points out the problems that come up when converting C/C++ to Python. Also a little sidenote: If you try to only `imshow` the image, just comment out the `normal *= 255`

Comment: Thanks for vectorized version. However, in [this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/82453/calculate-surface-normals-from-depth-image-using-neighboring-pixels-cross-product/) , they also used depth-map image and they got better results.

Comment: As stated on the link you posted: The original image they had was 32-bit. They only uploaded 8-bit, so we can never reproduce what they did there

Comment: oh, sorry, i didn't consider this. Thank for your all efforts.

Comment: why is the third dimension is one? ``normal = np.dstack((-zx, -zy, np.ones_like(d_im)))``

Comment: if you take a pixel and its neighbours C = (i, j), A = (i-1, j), B = (i, j-1) and if you assume that they correspond to the 3d points C = (i, j, depth(c)), A = (i-1, j, depth(a)), B = (i, j-1, depth(b)), the cross-product CA x CB is equal to [depth(C)-depth(A), depth(C)-depth(B), 1] = [-zx, -zy, 1]. (the assumption of the 3d points is not correct in real cases but that corresponds to the code posted by the author.)

Answer (score 0):

@sowlosc's answer don't take into account the camera intrinsics
@Baichuan's answer has obvious bugs

I implemented a brief, correct, fast, easy-to-use function `get_surface_normal_by_depth`nd compared with the revised @Baichuan's scheme, the correctness of the results was verified.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_surface_normal_by_depth(depth, K=None):
    """
    depth: (h, w) of float, the unit of depth is meter
    K: (3, 3) of float, the depth camere's intrinsic
    """
    K = [[1, 0], [0, 1]] if K is None else K
    fx, fy = K[0][0], K[1][1]

    dz_dv, dz_du = np.gradient(depth)  # u, v mean the pixel coordinate in the image
    # u*depth = fx*x + cx --> du/dx = fx / depth
    du_dx = fx / depth  # x is xyz of camera coordinate
    dv_dy = fy / depth

    dz_dx = dz_du * du_dx
    dz_dy = dz_dv * dv_dy
    # cross-product (1,0,dz_dx)X(0,1,dz_dy) = (-dz_dx, -dz_dy, 1)
    normal_cross = np.dstack((-dz_dx, -dz_dy, np.ones_like(depth)))
    # normalize to unit vector
    normal_unit = normal_cross / np.linalg.norm(normal_cross, axis=2, keepdims=True)
    # set default normal to [0, 0, 1]
    normal_unit[~np.isfinite(normal_unit).all(2)] = [0, 0, 1]
    return normal_unit

def get_normal_map_by_point_cloud(depth, K):
    height, width = depth.shape

    def normalization(data):
        mo_chang = np.sqrt(
            np.multiply(data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 0])
            + np.multiply(data[:, :, 1], data[:, :, 1])
            + np.multiply(data[:, :, 2], data[:, :, 2])
        )
        mo_chang = np.dstack((mo_chang, mo_chang, mo_chang))
        return data / mo_chang

    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, width), np.arange(0, height))
    x = x.reshape([-1])
    y = y.reshape([-1])
    xyz = np.vstack((x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    pts_3d = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(K), xyz * depth.reshape([-1]))
    pts_3d_world = pts_3d.reshape((3, height, width))
    f = (
        pts_3d_world[:, 1 : height - 1, 2:width]
        - pts_3d_world[:, 1 : height - 1, 1 : width - 1]
    )
    t = (
        pts_3d_world[:, 2:height, 1 : width - 1]
        - pts_3d_world[:, 1 : height - 1, 1 : width - 1]
    )
    normal_map = np.cross(f, t, axisa=0, axisb=0)
    normal_map = normalization(normal_map)
    return normal_map


vis_normal = lambda normal: np.uint8((normal + 1) / 2 * 255)[..., ::-1]

normal1 = get_surface_normal_by_depth(depth, K)    #  spend time: 60ms
normal2 = get_normal_map_by_point_cloud(depth, K)  #  spend time: 90ms

cv2.imwrite("normal1.png", vis_normal(normal1))
cv2.imwrite("normal2.png", vis_normal(normal2))
```

The result: normal1.png and normal2.png

[image: normal1.png]
[image: normal2.png]

Comment: What are the units of depth?

Comment: @DanGoodrick  depth's data type is float, units is meter

Answer (score -1):

The code (matrix calculation) should be:

```
def normalization(data):
   mo_chang =np.sqrt(np.multiply(data[:,:,0],data[:,:,0])+np.multiply(data[:,:,1],data[:,:,1])+np.multiply(data[:,:,2],data[:,:,2]))
   mo_chang = np.dstack((mo_chang,mo_chang,mo_chang))
   return data/mo_chang

x,y=np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,width),np.arange(0,height))
x=x.reshape([-1])
y=y.reshape([-1])
xyz=np.vstack((x,y,np.ones_like(x)))
pts_3d=np.dot(np.linalg.inv(K),xyz*img1_depth.reshape([-1]))
pts_3d_world=pts_3d.reshape((3,height,width))
f= pts_3d_world[:,1:height-1,2:width]-pts_3d_world[:,1:height-1,1:width-1]
t= pts_3d_world[:,2:height,1:width-1]-pts_3d_world[:,1:height-1,1:width-1]
normal_map=np.cross(f,l,axisa=0,axisb=0)
normal_map=normalization(normal_map)
normal_map=normal_map*0.5+0.5
alpha = np.full((height-2,width-2,1), (1.), dtype="float32")
normal_map=np.concatenate((normal_map,alpha),axis=2)
```

1. We should use the camera intrinsics named 'K'. I think the value f and t is based on 3D points in camera coordinate.
2. For the normal vector, the (-1,-1,100) and (255,255,100) are the same color in 8 bites images but they are totally different normal. So we should map the normal values to (0,1) by `normal_map=normal_map*0.5+0.5`.